# Why does AlphaGo Zero select move based on exponentiated visit count?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, alphago-zero

From [the AlphaGo Zero paper](https://deepmind.com/research/publications/mastering-game-go-without-human-knowledge), AlphaGo Zero uses an exponentiated visit count from the tree search.

Why use visit count instead of the mean action value $Q(s, a)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is surprisingly hidden in the original AlphaGo [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature16961):

> At the end of search AlphaGo selects the action with maximum visit count; this
>   is less sensitive to outliers than maximizing action value.

Unfortunately, there did not appear to be further details in the paper or in the related [reference](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5599855). The root child node (corresponding to an action) with maximum visit count is fittingly known as the *robust child*, as described [here](https://project.dke.maastrichtuniversity.nl/games/files/msc/Fschadd_thesis.pdf) and referenced in a MCTS survey [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6145622).

Comment: One obvious scenario where mean actual value falls short is when the count is small (say, 1).